# Basement subfloor (dricore) with existing exterior framing & insulation

Tags: insulation, basement, subfloor

Basement subfloor (Dricore) with existing exterior framing & insulation

I have a 2016-built house in Ottawa, Ontario with a basement that is largely unfinished (only the landing area was finished by the builder). The exterior basement walls were framed and filled with batt insulation (bottom layers removed in pictures for upcoming electrical installation). Against the foundation wall, there is black house-wrap paper as well as a small section of vapour barrier that extends up 6 inches from the floor and wraps underneath the bottom plate of the framing (photos 2+3). Of course, there was/would be another layer of vapour barrier before drywall goes up.

We're going to be installing Dricore as the subfloor system which I understand can be installed with existing walls/framing, although I also understand that building framing on top of the Dricore is preferred.

Does anyone have any advice or thoughts on using the existing insulation solution? Is it worth taking the framing down to re-build on top of Dricore/perhaps exploring an alternative insulation solution?

[image: existing exterior framing]

[image: bottom plate with vapour barrier]

[image: vapour barrier extending 6” up foundation wall]

Comment: You've got one layer of vapo(u)r barrier and you want to put up another one? That's a recipe for moisture collection between the barriers, leading to mold, mildew, rot, etc. Generally considered a Bad Idea™. Either that or I'm misreading your text (can't see the images right now, so maybe it's explained in the pictures).

Comment: Clay, did you try to edit your question under the user name "mods"? If so, please register your "Clay" account and you'll always be able to edit your own post without having to have it reviewed. At a minimum, return to the browser where you wrote the post - the cookies may still be there allowing you to edit it.

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks for the tip! I edited the post to clarify the vapour barrier - there is only a small section behind the black wrapping; it starts at 6” above the floor and extends underneath the bottom plate of the framing and up the other side to cover. There was a full layer of vapour barrier against the framing (removed in the pictures). This is how the builder did it in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I have laid many DriCore panels. I have had walls built on them and had it meet walls. Either way is good that I recall. Make sure your floor is flat enough, or get the shims that come with the system. Glueing is not needed in the T&G, but I did it anyway.